# Resolving CORS Issue Between Angular and Spring Boot Applications

Tags: angular, spring-boot

login:1

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/Backend/users/signin' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

[image]

suggested adding CORS configuration in the backend code to allow requests from the frontend application running at http://localhost:4200.

I provided a code example for the CORS configuration in Java using Spring Boot.

I suggested checking if the CORS configuration is correctly applied and loaded in the application, and also ensuring that the server is restarted after making changes.

I advised verifying that the backend server responds with the correct CORS headers, including the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header with the value 'http://localhost:4200'.

I recommended checking for any conflicts with other proxy or CORS configurations if using Angular CLI and proxy.conf.json.

I advised checking the server logs for any errors related to CORS requests.

Comment: Oui, cela répond partiellement à la question sur l'activation de CORS dans Spring Boot. Cependant, il semble qu'il y ait encore des problèmes liés à CORS qui ne sont pas résolus

Comment: You might want to write in English...

Comment: Yes, this partially answers the question about enabling CORS in Spring Boot. However, it seems that there are still some CORS related issues that are unresolved

Comment: "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/Backend/users/signin' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."